# How to detect file encoding in Octave?

Tags: encoding, octave

I am working with many XML files and some of them are UTF-8 while most are ANSI.

In the UTF-8 files, the XML header states:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO8859-1" ?>
```

However that information is wrong.

The problem this generates is that I  use `unicode2native` to generate correct XLS files, which generates bad output when the file is UTF-8 encoded.

How can I detect which is the real encoding of each file programmatically?

To manually locate them with the help of a text editor is not a feasible option, as there are hundreds of files, and my solution must work with more files which I don't have access.

Comment: Please clarify your question. With "correct XLS files" you are refering to the old Microsoft Excel file format? Which role plays encoding key/value pair if it's not correct? Are you on a POSIX system and can you call `ìconf` or `chardet` in a system call? Why do you use GNU Octave in the first place?

Comment: Correct XLS file is a XLS  file which doesn't show weird characters. I use Octave to generate descriptive statistics and to export summarized data to Excel. I am using Windows but the script may be executed by someone on another operating system. I found a way using the `file` tool in a `system` call on Windows, but I wanted to know the proper, pure Octave, way.

Answer (score 2):

There's no easy way to do this generally: because a given file might be a valid sequence in multiple encodings, detecting the character encoding requires using heuristics that are aware of natural language features, such as character frequencies, common words, and so on.

Octave doesn't have direct support for this. So you'll need to use an external program or library. Options include [ICU4C](http://userguide.icu-project.org/conversion/detection), [compact_enc_det](https://github.com/google/compact_enc_det), [chardet](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/), [juniversalchardet](https://github.com/albfernandez/juniversalchardet), and others. chardet would probably be the easiest for you to use, since you can just install it and call it as an external command, instead of building a custom program or oct-file using a library. Or juniversalchardet, since if you have a Java-enabled Octave build, it's easy to pull in and use Java libraries from Octave code.

If it's really true that your input files are all either ANSI (Windows 1252/ISO 8859-1) or UTF-8, and *no other* encodings, you might be able to get away with just checking each file's contents to see if it's a valid UTF-8 string, and assume that any that are not valid UTF-8 are ANSI. Only certain byte sequences are valid UTF-8 encodings, so there's a good chance that the ANSI-encoded files are not valid UTF-8. I think you can check whether a file is valid UTF-8 in pure Octave by doing `utf8_bytes = unicode2native(file_contents, 'UTF-8')` on it, and seeing if the `utf8_bytes` output is identical to just casting `file_contents` directly to `uint8`. If that doesn't work, you can fall back to using Java's character encoding support (and that you can do with Java Standard Library stuff on any Java-enabled Octave build, without having to load an external JAR file).

And if all your input files are either UTF-8 or strictly *7-bit* ASCII, then you can just treat them all as UTF-8, because 7-bit ASCII is a valid subset of UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Palliative solution that I found for Windows 10, while I can't find a proper way to do this in pure Octave:

```
[~, output] = system(['file --mime-encoding "', fileAddress, '"']);
encoding = strsplit(output)(columns(strsplit(output, ' '))){1};

if strcmp('utf-8', encoding)
  sheet(1, 1) = {strcat('', unicode2native(myText, 'ISO-8859-1'))};
else
  sheet(1, 1) = {myText};
endif
```